# Multiple Plots in Mayavi

Tags: python, data-visualization, mayavi

MATLAB has a `hold` function (if I remember correctly, it's been a while) to plot several things on the same "graph"/window. Is there anyway to do this in Mayavi? I'd like to visualize several realizations of a calculation, and have them all on the same graph. But I haven't been able to figure it out from reading the documentation.

Comment: see the last demo on this page: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html#visualizing-a-vector-field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the mlab module of mayavi, it will hold by default. Example:

```
In [1]: from mayavi import mlab

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: mlab.plot3d(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10))
Out[3]: <mayavi.modules.surface.Surface at 0x2a4eade0>

In [4]: mlab.plot3d(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10))
Out[4]: <mayavi.modules.surface.Surface at 0x28218ab0>

In [5]: mlab.plot3d(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10))
Out[5]: <mayavi.modules.surface.Surface at 0x2a51db40>

In [6]: mlab.plot3d(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10))
Out[6]: <mayavi.modules.surface.Surface at 0x2a840bd0>
```

The three plots will be in the same figure.

If you create a new figure, the new ones will be added to this new figure. You can also directly assign a new plot to a given figure with the `figure` keyword argument.